# Server Fault close reason text

Tags: support, close-reasons

I'm wondering if the Server Fault close message is still suitable give there's a [Network Engineering Stack Exchange](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/):

> Questions on professional server- or networking-related infrastructure
>   administration are off-topic for Stack Overflow unless they directly
>   involve programming or programming tools. You may be able to get help
>   on Server Fault.

It appears ***networking-related infrastructure*** and its ***administration*** are both [on-topic at Network Engineering  SE](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic). The Network Engineering SE even includes network design and hardware.

Should the Server Fault close reason drop the networking verbiage? Or should the verbiage remain but the close reason expanded to include Network Engineering?

Or is this a waste of time/moot point because most off-topic Stack Overflow questions are not on-topic or worthy of either site? (I.e., the close reason should be removed altogether and a custom message used when needed).

Comment: There's a number of SE sites, I'd like to see for a simple migration vote. But unfortunately those are either still in _Beta_ state, or didn't make it up to the _official_ list yet. :P ...

Comment: @πάντα ῥεῖ - yeah, I'd like to see one generic message that allows us to select a site from a dropdown. That way, I can learn about new sites, and I can make a suggestion to the user without typing it by hand.

Comment: **The close reason should remain, but it should stop suggesting a particular site.** Most of the questions people close with that reason shouldn't be reposted directly on Server Fault (or anywhere else) anyway. I use that one and the Super User reason a lot, but always with the reservation that I might be implicitly suggesting the question would be on-topic there when I know damn well otherwise.

Comment: 99.9% related: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/277872/2821954

Answer (score 2):

The way I'm usually going, is either to leave a comment that the question doesn't fit well for the current site's on-topic policies, and downvote and/or close vote for

- too broad
- unclear
- asking for off-site resources

<sub>These work well for most of the cases.</sub>

- own close reason (mentioning the alternative SE site), as a last resort

---

Other close vote reasons or site recommendations could fit well for such questions (e.g. posting working code for improvement, where SO is merely intended to fix not working code, should be better posted at e.g. [SE Codereview](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/))

Though, there aren't that many stable, and *non Beta state* sites on SE, that would fit well for such an unfiltered drop down selection as you propose (not to mention, this list might be too big to be handled conveniently).

Comment: *"not to mention, this list might be too big..."* - oh, that could be an issue. Perhaps the list should be held to technical sites, like Code Review and Server Fault; and avoid Sci Fi Stack Exchange and friends.