# Remove the mention of "Super User" from the standard off-topic close reasons

Tags: feature-request, close-reasons, migration, superuser

You currently have this close reason – emphasis mine:

> Questions about general computing hardware and software are off-topic for Stack Overflow unless they directly involve tools used primarily for programming. **You may be able to get help on Super User.**

Now, the problem is, there's also a direct migration path to Super User. What purpose does this close reason serve, then?

If a question is off topic for Stack Overflow, on topic for Super User, and *good enough* to be migrated, it should be migrated there directly. If it is not on topic for Super User (despite being about computer software or hardware), or not good enough, it should not be migrated, and – most importantly – we should not tell people that they get help on Super User.

Let's see what should really happen:

[image]

**Why the current situation is bad:**

It shouldn't say, "Yeah, well, you could ask on Super User", because what we see happening quite often is people asking off topic questions on Super User, [assuming it would have been fine](https://superuser.com/questions/844804/android-ios-wp-built-in-microphone-noise-reduction?noredirect=1#comment1113256_844804), because **they were told so**.

This leaves a bad user experience. First you're told to go somewhere else, and then people on the target site have to fix it and tell unexperienced users that they've been getting the wrong advice through an official message, signed by people who should've known better.

And I dare say the first close reason is also often chosen for questions about phones and electronic devices, which are off topic for Super User – but many close voters on Stack Overflow may not know that.

A few other issues: Those posts are usually just copy-pasted, and users on Stack Overflow might also be wondering why their question wasn't migrated directly. It encourages cross-posting ("hey, look over there!") rather than showing people that a question can be moved, or not telling folks about a site that will not help them anyway.

So please, remove the mention of Super User from the close reason, and let it simply say:

> Questions about general computing hardware and software are off-topic for Stack Overflow unless they directly involve tools used primarily for programming.

Vote to migrate all questions that are good enough for Super User and on topic there.

Comment: I just remembered… this was [brought up before on MSO before the split](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/186802/remove-mentions-of-other-sites-in-stack-overflow-off-topic-reasons) and closed there, so I guess it makes sense to ask it here.

Comment: "Vote to migrate..." Hmm... how do I vote to migrate?

Comment: @Louis You click "This question belongs on another site in the Stack Exchange network" and then choose the site. And… please don't take this personally, but seeing that you have 18k reputation on Stack Overflow, I find it, well, curious that you wouldn't know. Is the option really not as prominent as it could be?

Comment: That option is presented to me as a vote to close the question. That it *also* constitutes a *vote for migration* is not at all clear to me.

Comment: @Louis True, it does not say "migrate" anywhere, although that's the official term for it. Perhaps that's another possible change request for all sites.

Comment: You *sure* you want to encourage more migration?

Comment: At least for me, I think that option would be for posts that potentially could go to Super User but aren't great yet so we don't migrate them.  There are times we get custom requests that are off-topic for SO and could be on-topic but are quality enough to move, so I'll use that option as a close reason.

Comment: @bluefeet But in such a case, it does not tell the users that their post needs to be improved. If you know a question could potentially go there, but needs a bit of editing, then you'd *have* to tell the user what specifically they need to change. Or at least the close reason should be very explicit in mentioning that the post is not yet good enough for migration and should not be copypasted to the other site.

Comment: @slhck True, I guess if the this remains in place then possibly the message should be updated to include that wording.

Comment: @Shog9 I don't think we have a big problem with incoming migrations. At least not of the scale SF had when they went off the list. I just want it to be unambiguous for new users. Removal of SU from that close reason probably would not increase the number of migrations significantly. Plus, close voters would have to agree with 4/5 anyway, right?

Comment: When a question gets asked on Stack Overflow that is off-topic there, but is on-topic on Super User, *but is probably already asked on SU* then I don't want to migrate it and create a duplicate. I want the OP to go look for the answer on the correct site.

Comment: So... The month after we rolled out that close reason, the number of migration votes for Super User dropped from 4755 to 1173, and mostly continued dropping - last month we saw 457. That's votes, not flags and not closures - as you note, it takes 4 out of 5 votes to actually migrate a question. Still... That's a *massive* drop. I think it's worth keeping in mind.

Comment: @Shog9 Thanks for running the numbers. That's worth considering. But still, I wonder if people, when not feeling too strongly about migrating a question, wouldn't rather just err for the generic close reason. (A/B testing would be nice…)

Comment: @BilltheLizard Similar to what bluefeet mentioned above, in such a case you'd have to specifically tell users to go search though, right? I wouldn't assume they'd see the link to Super User and – instead of just copypasting their question – search for an answer.

Comment: If their question gets closed on SO, then they copy/paste it to SU, that's no different from a migration. If only *some* people search on SU instead of doing that, we're still ahead. (But maybe the close message should explicitly tell people to look for an answer before posting on SU? That seems reasonable to me.)

Comment: Generic is bad, @slhck; they just create more work when folks come *here* to ask questions about where they should ask their question. We could consider a "where to ask hardware/software questions that aren't programming questions" topic though.

Comment: Also, I'm not wild about a/b testing close reasons - every time we change these, folks get confused, and changing them for a random sample of people would be even more confusing. We can change close reasons and compare before/after though; that'll have to be good enough.

Comment: @Shog9 I'd like that part where you link to a FAQ-style page instead of one site. Then you could redirect all things Android, iOS, etc. as well.

Comment: @BilltheLizard But that's the whole point. If they don't know about SU (because it's not mentioned), they can't copypaste it there. We don't want these bad questions to be copypasted. We *want* the good questions to be migrated. And yes, briefly telling people to improve the post / search for an answer, might help. At least better than not telling them to.

Comment: @slhck I'm not talking about bad posts. I just close those for another reason. It's decent questions that I suspect are probably already covered on SU that I direct there without migrating.

Comment: It might be appropriate to migrate the question ["Remove mentions of other sites in Stack Overflow off topic reasons"](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/186802/remove-mentions-of-other-sites-in-stack-overflow-off-topic-reasons) to Meta.SO from Meta.SE and point this request at that.

Comment: @BilltheLizard and then clarification comments that were asked and answered on SO don't get moved to SU.  Nor do any answers that happened to have been posted.  Is a duplicate and merge more or less problematic than an identical post on two sites that increases the overall noise and adds to the difficulty of finding the answer for the person searching?

Comment: @MichaelT If a question is off-topic on SO and probably answered on SU, I'm not concerned about comments and answers that came from SO in most cases. They don't need to be migrated and merged. The points your raise are just more reasons that people need to be directed to the correct site.

Comment: @BilltheLizard they do.  However, canned off topic messages rarely offers sufficient and nuanced guidance necessary to help the person asking the question for how to move the question to the other site - or for that matter even if its a good question there (one of the biggest issues with mentioning non-migration target sites) - people will pick it, even if it is too broad, or unclear, or primary opinion.  Don't migrate crap and don't *suggest* reposting crap. As a mod to a non-migration site, you have control over the first. The later is often done by people trying to get it off of SO.

Comment: @Shog9 *The month after we rolled out that close reason, the number of migration votes for Super User dropped from 4755 to 1173.* That could also show that the close reason itself is effective at reducing migrations, regardless of whether or not it mentions "Super User". It's not really a case for leaving "Super User" in that close reason, but it *is* a case for leaving that general close reason, "Super User" mention or not - which nobody is arguing against. Those numbers don't make the case that "not mentioning Super User in the close reason would increase migrations".

Comment: If none of you noticed already, the OP is a [su] moderator...just throwing that out there.

Comment: @slhck you might want to chime in on this discussion. https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/368924/should-we-improve-the-closing-flagging-and-voting-dialogues

Answer (score 53):

**Yes, please!**

### Background

[Back then](https://stackexchange.com/sites?view=list#oldest), there is only 1 site to ask questions about general computing hardware and software, the [Super User](https://superuser.com/). Thus, the closure message seems to be appropriate at that time.

Then, Stack Exchange keeps growing, spawning sites like [AskUbuntu](https://askubuntu.com/), [Unix & Linux](https://unix.stackexchange.com/), [Ask Different](https://apple.stackexchange.com/), [Android Enthusiasts](http://android.stackexchange.com), etc.

Now, the closure message seems suggesting to **always** ask those on Super User, *disregarding other more appropriate sites*. Every time I flag [android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android)-usage questions with this, a part of my soul gets torn, since I also have to let user knows the existence of Android.SE. Meanwhile, look at [how often Android questions on Super User got closed](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/android?sort=newest).

### Proposal

I was starting to be active on Android.SE, and not so often finding a question related to developing an Android app. Of course, the first thing that pop-ups in my mind is to flag it. Now, this is one of the off-topic reasons:

> Questions about writing and publishing Android apps, writing custom ROMs, and other topics that are primarily of concern to developers are off-topic. Consider taking advantage of [other resources](https://android.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/371/where-can-i-ask-questions-that-arent-android-enthusiast-questions) that may be appropriate for your question.

Instead of pointing it directly to Stack Overflow, it provides a link. Clicking the link goes to a post on [its meta](https://android.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/371/where-can-i-ask-questions-that-arent-android-enthusiast-questions), which seems to be inspired by [its MSO counterpart](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/254567/2821954). But here's a difference: Meta Android.SE lists so many alternatives, which I really appreciate it.

Also, [Shog mentions something similar to this in the comment](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/277872/remove-the-mention-of-super-user-from-the-standard-off-topic-close-reasons#comment121901_277872)

> We could consider a "where to ask hardware/software questions that aren't programming questions" topic though.

which I and [the OP agreed to](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/277872/remove-the-mention-of-super-user-from-the-standard-off-topic-close-reasons#comment121906_277872)

> I'd like that part where you link to a FAQ-style page instead of one site. Then you could redirect all things Android, iOS, etc. as well.

So, my proposal is either:

- Remove the offending sentence, as proposed by OP, or
- Follow Android.SE approach, as proposed similarly by Shog. (**Preferred**)

Comment: which one would you prefer? I personally would prefer link-to-post approach, and my upvote went to that one. I'm not sure which one I'm supporting if you have two options in the post.

Comment: I also preferred that one. Instead of leaving users without any hint, it's preferable to guide them!

Comment: And on a similar point - ServerFault is also recommended as a place to re-ask. (And it isn't often the appropriate place)

Answer (score 13):

Rather than hard-coded superuser/serverfault close options I would like to see a general-purpose close option where you can specify the site that an otherwise decent but off-topic question should ideally be migrated to (with e.g. a popup menu of common sites to select from). Some sites that I would like to see on the list:

- meta
- superuser
- serverfault
- codereview.SE
- DSP.SE
- electronics.SE
- maths.SE
- apple.SE
- askubuntu

Comment: Well, that's basically what the migration option already does, although with fewer sites. For a good reason, because some sites are a superset of some other sites in terms of scope, and people could never decide on where to migrate to. (E.g. you'd end up with people voting for Ask Ubuntu and Super User, although Ubuntu questions are on topic for both of them.)

Comment: That might be true for e.g. superuser/askubuntu, but I regularly see questions on SO which unambiguously belong on DSP/electronics/apple/maths/etc, and there is no satisfactory way of dealing with them, other than writing out an explanation, or flagging them for migration, both of which require more effort than is really necessary. It really ought to be a lot quicker/easier to deal with these relatively common cases.

Comment: You forgot `/dev/null` ;)

Comment: A generic migration option has been discussed at length and rejected categorically (search [meta.se] ).  It won't happen.

Comment: @TheBlueDog We could vote to migrate to [http://devnull-as-a-service.com/dev/null](http://devnull-as-a-service.com/dev/null).