# When to vote to close and when to vote to migrate

Tags: discussion, close-reasons, migration

For Stack Overflow, you can give either of the following reasons for closure:

1. Questions about general computing hardware and software are
   off-topic for Stack Overflow unless they directly involve tools used
   primarily for programming. You may be able to get help on Super
   User.
2. Belongs on another Stack Exchange network (list includes SuperUser).

These seem almost identical, really. So my question is, how do you know when to vote to migrate and when to vote to close? My assumption is that if the question is off topic on Stack Overflow but on topic for SuperUser you should vote to migrate and if it's off topic for both sites you should just vote to close - is that correct? If that's correct, why does it include the phrase "You may be able to get help on Super User?"

Comment: "You may be able to get help on Super User?" is not a migration close reason to my knowledge.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov It's part of the text for closing a question for being about general software/hardware.

Comment: @EJoshuaS I don't believe it leads to migration. Only "close-> off-topic->belongs to other SE site" will cause migration as far as I know (I rarely pick that reason - so could be wrong).

Comment: Related: [Remove the mention of “Super User” from the standard off-topic close reasons](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/277872/4639281)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

## [Don't migrate crap](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/91446/165773)

If the question would be on-topic on the target site **in its current state**, vote to migrate.

If the question would be closed on the target site **in its current state**, don't migrate it.

When a migrated question is closed on the target site, the migration is rejected, and the target site gets a big mess to deal with.

#### When in doubt, don't migrate it.

Comment: I would add "if you ready to upvote question" as condition to vote for migration...

Comment: It can be on-topic but not worthy of an upvote @Alexei

Comment: In all my years of voting to close questions, I think I've picked the "migrate to SU" path *once*. Maybe twice.