# Why does the "recommend and find a book, or tool" ... close explanation not mention softwarereqs?

Tags: discussion, recommendation-questions

Other close reasons explicitly mention other SE network sites, such as superuser.com or segfault.

Why does the close reason for "recommend and find" not have sentence pointing to [softwarerecs](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/)? (maybe asking the user to first study the policies of that community)?

Comment: `maybe asking the user to first study the policies of that community` it's not realistic to assume that will happen after the user posted a question on SO without first studying the policies of *that* community. This would likely result in a great number of bad questions showing up on softwarereqs

Comment: Regarding "Other close reasons explicitly mention other SE network sites", there's actually a highly supported feature request to remove them instead: [Remove the mention of “Super User” from the standard off-topic close reasons](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/277872/2821954)

Comment: Because software recommendations don't want it to say that I imagine.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The far majority of resource requests on Stack Overflow, do not fit Software Recommendations well.

Software Recommendations has [very strict requirements](https://softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/336/35246) (also linked from their Help Center). The resource requests posted on Stack Overflow rarely ever fit these requirements.

If we were to tell them, "here's another SE site for software recommendations", chances are, they'll post there without regard for that site's requirements. As  Pekka 웃 observed in their [comment](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/370255/why-does-the-recommend-and-find-a-book-or-tool-close-explanation-not-ment#comment604390_370255), it's unlikely that a user who already posted on SO without studying the rules here, would study the further rules for Software Recommendations SE.

Most of the time, these askers are better off not knowing about Software Recommendations SE. It's just going to add to everybody's frustration. It will be frustrating for the Software Recommendations users because they get another bad question. And it will be frustrating for the asker who now gets their question downvoted and closed on Software Recommendations just like it was on Stack Overflow.

Only if they have a clear set of requirements and show that they made some effort to solve their problem themselves, are such questions candidates for migration or reposting.

Comment: “askers are better off not knowing about Software Recommendations SE“. Regardless of questions quality, askers should be aware, that questions about Software Recommendations should be asked on https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/. At the same time providing the link to https://softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/336/35246 will be important