# Add a link to Super User if the question is closed as "About general computing hardware and software" but not migrated

Tags: discussion, feature-request, close-reasons, closed-questions

I noticed something weird. I recently voted to close a question as "About general computing hardware and software". Inside of the close reason section, we can find this description:

> [image]

There we can find a direct link to Super User to make the close voter a picture of Super User, helping in their decision whether this close reason is appropriate or not.

The question got closed, but surprisingly there is no link to Super User for the OP itself inside of the close description, only a suggestion to edit their question to be on-topic to Stack Overflow:

> [image]

"*on-topic*" contains a hyperlink to https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic where you can find a link to Super User among other links to Stack Exchange sites at the bottom of the page, but it's pretty hidden and unclear to find. "Computer enthusiasts and power users" also seems for me not a well-descriptive information for that community, that you can/should place such questions there.

> [image]

---

It is strange that the OP, which is in my experience at the most times a new user to Stack Overflow and the network in general, does not get a direct link to the according community while we as close voters, which I guess are for the most part already familiar about Super User, do.

Many times, I advice them to go to Super User instead by a comment of myself, but that shouldn't be. It should be clear where to go and not be in the hands of some user who take a care.

#### My suggestion:

> "We don’t allow questions about general computing hardware and software on Stack Overflow. You can [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/help/editing) the question so it’s [on-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) for Stack Overflow or ask the question on [Super User](https://superuser.com/)."

---

<sub>Side note: I didn't tested, but this might be equivalent at the "About professional server- or networking-related infrastructure administration" closing with a missing link to Server Fault. So, if there is an edit to the wording, maybe consider to place a direct link to Server Fault in the close wording similar to the proposed suggestion there, too.</sub>

Comment: This sounds like an excellent idea. I'd expect that link to be more helpful to an OP of a closed question than the person flagging.

Comment: Counter proposal from 2014: [Remove the mention of “Super User” from the standard off-topic close reasons](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/277872/2821954)

Comment: More similar discussions can be found https://meta.stackoverflow.com/search?q=more+migration+targets ... The question would benefit from explanation why pointing more users to SU would be beneficial for SU (which is general problem with such feature requests about migration proposals - considering SO/current user and ignoring needs of target site).

Comment: If these questions were high quality, why are they not being migrated, to Super User instead of just being closed?

Answer (score 11):

The only reason why I disagree with this notion is that there is no guarantee whatsoever that the OP will take the time to *ensure* that their question belongs on that site, or that it hasn't been asked before.

Maybe this is one way of reducing the deluge of crap questions that hit up smaller network sites by not making it more accessible...

Comment: There will never be a guarantee for that, but that's not the subject of this post. The subject of this post is to provide the same guidance to an OP like SO does with the close voters.

Comment: If the question would be off-topic to Super User, SO shouldn't suggest the close voters that such question would fit better there either, while it in fact doesn't. If this is true, there is a lack of logic and transparency within the closing procedure itself.

Comment: And if the question would be really "crap", in 99% of all cases it wouldn't be closed to would better fit on another community then either. Then it would closed as "Needs details or clarity" or "Needs more focus" or would be deleted before even trying to get it to there.

Comment: "There will never be a guarantee for that, but that's not the subject of this post" ...except it *is*.  [A question is automatically migrated to the close target site](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/10250/175248) if all three of the close votes point it to the target site; in this case, Super User.  If *one* user doesn't believe it does, then that's still a valid perspective to respect and honor, and there's really no reason to try and push them to another site if there wasn't consensus among the close voters to do so.

Comment: @RobertSsupportsMonicaCellio: Just know that migration has had so much baggage attached to it, especially related to migrations *from* Stack Overflow.  Anything at all to help stymie the flow of utter crap that is migrated between sites is always welcome, and any decision to alter that needs to be vigorously defended.  You have failed to convince me that there is sufficient cause to introduce this link without it resulting in more crap questions making their way around the network.

Comment: But I think there should be at least a hint to the site, where it is likely to be on-topic in case it doesn't get migrated. Why not just providing that information for someone seeking help to solve their problem? If some user think the question would better fit there according to what SO proposed them, then OP should be able to get that information, too. I don't talk about horrible questions. They would be closed with another reason, not the reason that it would better fit to another community. I talk about questions which are good and have a high potential to fit to the target, but...

Comment: ...are just placed on the wrong site. Why not give OP then the chance to get their problem solved by linking them to the right and appropriate community?

Comment: @RobertSsupportsMonicaCellio: I admire your optimism.  But the problem is that questions are closed for bad reasons.  Bad questions are often sent across the fence.  In that defensive posture, I'm going to push you again on putting a link here:  in the historical context that we've had with question migration and people cross-posting questions, why should we *encourage* that when we have concrete evidence and proof that we've had crap questions proliferate on the network instead of die where they stand?

Comment: @RobertSsupportsMonicaCellio:  As a devil's advocate: if the question were good and worthy of migration, it'd be on the target site instead of... *not*.

Answer (score 8):

The vast majority of questions I vote to close as general computing would be low-quality even if they weren't off-topic, presumably because people who don't bother to check if their question is on-topic don't bother reading any of the other guidelines either. Super User doesn't want those questions any more than we do.

If you think the question has potential, a custom-tailored comment explaining what they need to do to improve it before reposting would be much more valuable than a canned message. For the rare gems that are already high-quality, you can just vote to migrate it directly instead.

If a link to Super User is going to be added to the close message, I think it at least needs to be accompanied with some sort of warning to make sure it follows their question guidelines.

Comment: 'accompanied with some sort of warning to make sure it follows their question guidelines' - why would a user who did not check the SO rules/policy bother with reading the rules/policy of some other site?  They won't, and will repost their question regardless.