# Closed question post-notice fails to display closer's choice that another Stack Exchange site is appropriate

Tags: discussion, feature-request, closed-questions

This is another iteration of this topic. After the last changes to the close selections (a year or two ago), when a question was closed the display mirrored the closer's choice if for "General Computing" and offered the [Super User](http://superuser.com/) link (or whatever the other appropriate Stack Exchange site would be).

That worked well, but over the past year I notice that had fallen off. That is bad, failing to communicate the appropriate in-house site that the user should be directed to.

Case-on-point, tonight, all 3 close votes for [Arch Installation : Was able to install everything over WiFi after initially connecting to it using iwctl. The problems arise thereafter (Continued)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/70648966/3422102) appropriately chose the "General Computing" reason, but there was no referral at all on the close reason to [Super User](http://superuser.com/). Nothing at all, e.g.

[image]

In the close dialog where the closer makes the choice, it states that "general computing questions are appropriate on Super User...", but that information no longer appears on the close message.

Instead the general edit message is shown - "You can edit the question so it's on-topic for Stack Overflow." -- no, no, you can't. That's the problem, these questions are not the edit to make on-topic type and why referral to the proper site is important.

Why do we no longer provide a link to the proper site when closing for general computing, or Unix & Linux, or Networking questions?

Comment: Since [the update to post notices](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/339700/241919), there are 3 types of view: OP, close voter (privileged), public (non-privileged). What you saw was the close voter (privileged), but there's still a possibility that there's an additional message to the OP mentioning Super User (need mods to confirm this).

Comment: That said, there's also an old discussion regarding the issue of mentioning a specific site [su]: [Remove the mention of "Super User" from the standard off-topic close reasons](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/277872/2821954)

Comment: Thanks @AndrewT., I just want to make sure the user is seeing something different than I see. Otherwise, the site is giving the user incorrect information. The question cannot be edited to be on topic.

Comment: As far as I know, when questions are closed as "more suitable on foo.SE", they go into a queue to be reviewed at that site, and if the reviewers consider it to be on-topic there, the question is automatically migrated. It doesn't seem to me that instructing the user to ask the question on that site, bypassing that review queue, would be a good idea. The question may also be a duplicate of one on foo.SE in which case asking it there is also not the right thing for the OP to do.

Comment: @kaya3 that's only true for the migration close reasons: Close -> A community-specific reason -> This question belongs on another site in the Stack Exchange network. OP talks about a different close reason: Close -> A community-specific reason -> About general computing hardware and software. That one does not do anything extra but show a different close message. Same as everything that's not under "This question belongs on another site in the Stack Exchange network"

Comment: @VLAZ OK, then I misunderstood - thank you for the clarification.

Comment: Finally, we removed super user from the close reason. Now we need to tell people that is not programming, so we have a more sensible close reason that applies correctly to many scenarios.

Comment: It seems that Super User is removed from the Closed question post notice for reason. However, edit link still stands and people keep editing their completely off topic question hoping they will be reopened. At least, offering edit should be removed, too. I would probably add notice that question might be on topic on some other SE site, offering link to list of sites, with a warning that OP must read the site's help center first before posting in order to find whether question is appropriate there or not.

Answer (score 13):

There's no need for that particular message, and it's arguably counterproductive. If a question is suitable for Super User, people can just vote to migrate it there straight away - there's already a standard migration path for that.

That should only happen with high-quality questions, though; a good heuristic for me is whether I would be willing to upvote the question if it was posted on the site that I'm proposing that it be migrated to. If so, I vote to migrate; if not, I vote to close.

So really, if we vote to close something as general computing, we're saying that we think that it's off-topic here **and** that we don't believe that it's suitable for "direct" migration to Super User. That being said, it really doesn't make sense to direct people there in the close message.

Comment: To migrate, we have needed to flag the question and request the migration. What I worry about is the close message providing no guidance to the user and it coming across as "Go away, you are not wanted here." Which it very much does. Now we can expect every user that comes and asks a question to click the links and go read how-to-ask and what's on-topic and search for what other StackExchange site is proper (and that's a valid position to take). But -- that's not the real-world. A new use comes asking for help and is slapped with a Question Closed. They go away and don't come back.

Comment: @David [Super User is a valid target](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZEnFN.png) for user initiated migration. Based on the [migration stats](https://stackoverflow.com/tools/posts/migrated/stats) (10k rep +), few migrated questions are subsequently closed there. Only 9% of 32 migrated questions in the last 90 days. I'm with EJoshuaS, I only vote to migrate questions that are high quality and have a good possibility of being answered.

Comment: Yes, that's' true and that dialog is very welcomed. But the dialog before it provides the reason for closure being due to "General Computing Questions..." and lists Super User, but that does not trigger migration. "This question belongs to ..." entry in the migration list duplicates most of the 1st entry on the prior dialog. I guess the way to look at it is if the question is good enough to migrate, use the migration, if not choose the 1st entry for closure, but that would seem to inject a lot of subjectivity into the choice. (not sure how to make that better)

Answer (score 8):

I don't have a concrete answer, but I bet it's because there's too many of them and their scopes overlap.

For example, the question you linked would be on topic on Unix & Linux **and** Super User, but probably better suited to Unix & Linux. For a more complicated hypothetical example, what about a question about using a web app on Ubuntu on [WSL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Subsystem_for_Linux)? Should that go to [Web Apps](https://webapps.stackexchange.com), [Ask Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com), or Super User? I'd rather close under the generic reason, leave a comment with site recommendations, and let OP decide, like this:

> `SO is for programming questions only, so this is [off-topic](/help/on-topic). You could ask on [webapps.se], [ubuntu.se], or [su] instead, depending on where you think the problem lies (the website, Ubuntu/WSL, or Windows, respectively).`

Comment: +1 for specific comments. I try to do that as much as possible when I VTC, for *any* reason. There's way too much "Downvote, VTC, and move on" here. While I've seen lots of arguments that (especially new) users ignore comments, that's not been my experience universally. I typically get at least one comment a day saying something like "*I edited my question, can you please come back and take a look?*" I have a ton of canned comments I can copy-paste covering just about every common scenario, and I customize them as necessary to fit the question.