# Was the close vote applied justly or not on my questions about procfs?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, scope, closed-questions, reopen-closed

I spent considerable time researching and crafting a question which was unlucky enough to get a downvote from one of the first 3 to see it because it dared to ask more than one related questions at once.
Thus cursed, it was doomed to be closed later.

(But it seems this now requires only 2 votes not 3 or 4 as it used to. When did this change?)

So I asked two related questions separately and had to refer comments from one to the other.
Perhaps demonstrating that one question would have been better.

While I was doing this both of these questions were closed with single "golden" votes from the same user as "Not suitable for this site".

(I thought this only applied to duplicate questions - [When did I get close-vote superpowers?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254589/when-did-i-get-close-vote-superpowers),
but apparently any moderator can do it.)

So today I am finding Stack Overflow particularly unwelcoming.
Perhaps I should just flag them for moderator attention but I may as well go the whole hog and endure the meta effect as well.
What is wrong with my two questions?

- [Given we have `/proc/pid/status` why do we still have `/proc/pid/stat`?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71864123/given-we-have-proc-pid-status-why-do-we-still-have-proc-pid-stat)
- [Is it better practice to use `/proc/pid/stat` or `/proc/pid/status`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71864081/it-better-practice-to-use-proc-pid-stat-or-proc-pid-status)

Was the <s>mighty Mjölnir wielded</s> instant close vote applied justly or not? Please explain.

A question about which API to use is better practice is surely on topic for Stack Overflow rather than superuser.

Also note:

https://superuser.com/help/on-topic

> and it is not about …
>
> programming and software development,

So superuser is definitely wrong.
Voting to close as opinion based *might* be more reasonable.

Another bullet point against superuser:

- [Remove the mention of "Super User" from the standard off-topic close reasons](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/277872/remove-the-mention-of-super-user-from-the-standard-off-topic-close-reasons)

Though I typically find that opinions matter. If the majority view is that X is better than Y or Y should be deprecated it is useful to know. I think that close reason should be reserved for when there is higher risk of conflict.

---

After consideration I believe the following:

My first question was off-topic.
I have replaced it with a slightly improved question on unix&linux

- https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/699019/given-we-have-the-api-proc-pid-status-should-could-proc-pid-stat-be-deprecated

However, I believe my second question i.e.

[Is it better practice to use `/proc/pid/stat` or `/proc/pid/status`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71864081/it-better-practice-to-use-proc-pid-stat-or-proc-pid-status)

Is on topic. More over my answer for both questions is the same:

- https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/699264/162453

It is better practice to use /proc/pid/status because, in my opinion at least, /proc/pid/stat should be deprecated. /proc/pid/stat is harder to parse correctly and failure to do so can result in subtle bugs and a possible security risk.

Comment: Small point of clarification, your questions were closed by an elected community moderator, not a gold badge holding regular user closing a question as a duplicate. The latter is what "Mjölnir" is used to describe. Community moderators can perform any action unilaterally and always have been able to. Flagging for moderator attention about the closure is not appropriate, since your questions *already* received moderator attention. You have already taken the redress available to you, posting here on Meta.

Comment: I honestly don't see where you see something about "programming [or] software development" in your questions so it would be off-topic on superuser.

Comment: Related: [When is Stack Overflow going to stop demonizing the quality-concerned users who have made the site a success?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/366858/when-is-stack-overflow-going-to-stop-demonizing-the-quality-concerned-users-who)

Comment: @EJoshuaS-StandwithUkraine to clarify. How is this related? Presumably that post is talking about the quality concerned curators and moderators rather than users like me? am I the demon for feeling unwelcome?

Comment: The title of the second question does not compute. For example, is it supposed to be *"Is it better practice to use /proc/pid/stat or /proc/pid/status?"*?

Comment: I was trying to use back tick formating in the title where its not applicable if that's what you meant.

Answer (score -3, accepted):

From my point of view, the question [Given we have `/proc/pid/status` why do we still have `/proc/pid/stat`?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71864123/given-we-have-proc-pid-status-why-do-we-still-have-proc-pid-stat) IS **about programming**:

1. It has ultimate programming goal and specifies the problem:

   > This was originally prompted by a desire to extract vmPeak, vmSize, vmRSS & vmHWM from within an application.
2. It scopes instruments which could be used for resolve the problem: `/proc/<pid>/status` or `/proc/<pid>/stat`.

   Because instruments are *files*, the actual programming language is secondary.
3. It asks about **policies** when one instrument should be preferred to another one in a **program**.

I am not sure whether such policies exist, but I *feel* they do.
Even if they do not exist, the question could be closed as "opinion based", but not because it is not about programming.

## Relation of procfs with programming

It is true that files can be read both by a programmer and by a "PC user" without a programming knowledge. It is also true that many of files under `/proc` could be understandable by a "PC user".

But it is also true that files under `/proc` constitute **API for programs**.

Take a look into file `/proc/<pid>/stat`. Example of its content:

```
10 (bash) S 9 10 10 34816 458 4210944 1603 34436 29 200 8 0 70 15 20 0 1 0 319 10432512 1281 18446744073709551615 94023103057920 94023103964933 140733037387520 0 0 0 65536 3670020 1266777851 1 0 0 17 2 0 0 30 0 0 94023104195824 94023104243204 94023128383488 140733037394248 140733037394254 140733037394254 140733037395950 0
```

It is not very useful for a *non-programmer* person, isn't it?

`man proc` describes format of that file and notes "This is used by ps(1).". But it is unclear from `man proc` whether given file is intended to be used in other programs, which are not part of Linux-based OS. Asking about that seems for me to be perfectly on-topic on Stack Overflow.

For example, [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39066998/what-are-the-meaning-of-values-at-proc-pid-stat) about `/proc/<pid>/stat`, which has been perfectly received on Stack Overflow.

Comment: It is really unfortunate the attitude this community has towards shell scripting sometimes. This is no more off topic than provider questions in PowerShell, because those could also be boiled down to "just paths" by the uninitiated. `/proc` is 100% an API most often used in systems programming, exposed as a "file system" in Unix because "everything is a file". It's just how some information is consumed, but these aren't files in the traditional sense of the word.

Comment: +1 we should be much more tolerant, about off topic and it is often difficult to determine if it is offtopic or not, in my point of view more in dubio pro reo less closure and deletion

Comment: It's often going to be *how* the problem is approached as to whether it's programmatic in nature. Troubleshooting problems with `/proc` not providing the correct information I would agree is off topic here. Questions about how to consume this as an API from scripts **is and should be on topic for Stack Overflow**. Asking about why there are two similar endpoints of an API would be on topic for any other language/environment. To be clear, these questions would fit under [su] and Unix/Linux, but they also fit here because they are programmatic in nature.

Comment: I'd recommend to re-write "It asks about policies when one instrument should be preferred to another one in a program." - it reads as "but this question must be closed as opinion-based" while you are trying to argue that it is on-topic... Quite confusing.

Comment: The mere fact that something was motivated by a programming task doesn't make it a programming question. Nearly all of my Super User questions were general computing problems that I encountered while programming, for example, and none of them are on-topic on this site.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov: Are questions about programming *policies* off-topic on Stack Overflow? There are "high-level" policies, which could be better asked on other sites (e.g. "Programmers"), but I saw many question on SO about "low-level" policies. E.g. a recent question about policies in the tag I follow: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71855535/cmake-target-compile-options-vs-target-compile-definitions.

Comment: @Tsyvarev most of the time "should I use X or Y" are off-topic as opinion-based. In rare cases (like "Should I parameterize my SQL query or use string concatenation") there is a definitive answer, but it may not be obvious to asker which bucket the question falls into - I believe two linked questions are completely opinion-based as it does not look like there is a strong guidance there. It also very likely questions that can be answered with specific guidance will be downvoted as such guidance likely to be spelled out everywhere one of the options is mentioned.

Comment: I agree that questions "should I use X or Y" are in risk to fall into category "there is no preference between X and Y, use any of them" and I see many such questions even in my favorite tags (e.g. "Which structure of files fits better for my CMake project"). But from my understanding, each such question should be **examined separately**, and for close a question as "opinion-based" one should be a **domain expert** at some extent. Are you sure that there is no guidance about using `/proc/<pid>/stat` file from e.g. Linux kernel developers, who actually "create" that file?

Comment: "ps(1)" See what [the man page numbers in parentheses mean](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62972/3404097).

Comment: @philipxy: How is this related to the question? I am perfectly aware what this `1` means.

Comment: I have added an update to my meta question now I believe both questions have the same clear umabiguous answer.
I also note that the example of a well received procfs question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39066998/what-are-the-meaning-of-values-at-proc-pid-stat - is exactly the sort which infuriates. It is a simple RTFM or google at best to find the answer.

Answer (score 23):

Yes, the closure of these questions by a moderator was correct. Neither of those questions have anything to do with software development. They are questions about the `/proc` file system in Linux. Stack Overflow is limited to programming questions. You can ask questions about Linux over on [Unix/Linux](https://unix.stackexchange.com) and/or [Super User](https://superuser.com). (There is no need to *migrate* either of those questions to another site automatically, since they haven't been answered. They can just be deleted here and re-posted elsewhere.)

Note that, as pointed out by Ian Campbell in the comments, this has nothing to do with Mjölnir, which refers to duplicate closure by users holding a gold tag badge. Your questions weren't closed as duplicates; they were closed as off-topic.

Comment: The procfs filesystem is an API. It is the only way to programmatically obtain process information on Linux without writing a kernel module. That is clearly a programming question.
Otherwise why even have a procfs tag on stackoverflow?

Comment: The existence of a tag doesn't mean that all questions about that thing are on-topic. We have a tag for Windows, but you can't ask how to change the screensaver on your computer; that's off-topic. The mere fact that something *can* be used as an API doesn't make all questions about it programming questions. Your questions aren't in the context of any software development. You're just asking about a kernel feature.

Comment: The word kernel implies a programmer. Most ordinary users do not even know what a kernel is.

Comment: Haha, no, the word kernel doesn't imply a programmer. The kernel is a basic part of the Linux operating system, present whether you're a programmer or not, and something which non-programmer users interact with frequently, including system and network administrators. ProcFS is *not* something that *only* a programmer would encounter (i.e., it's not a C API that is accessible only to a kernel driver), since it's presented as part of the standard file system that any user could see by simply listing a directory.

Comment: That's not entirely a fair analogy given the unix philosophy that "everything is a file". It would be reasonable to expect users even admins  to use ps or top in preference to /proc unless they are writing a script - which makes them a programmer.

Comment: @BruceAdams your questions look almost like [boat programming](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/14470/241919), "just because it mentions programming doesn't mean it's about programming". Many command-line tools can be used in scripting/programming, but the detail about how those tools work is not necessarily about programming.

Comment: Put it this way. If someone was writing a book about how to use this API would they recommend using stat or status. Similarly if someone is looking dispassionately at its design what would their criticisms be. Who would such a book be aimed at? software developers.

Comment: I am a programmer. When I have a sysadmin question I try to go to superuser or unix&linux. When I have a programming question I go to stackoverflow. Stackoverflow is my default choice as it matches my job description. Sometimes I get it wrong. unix and linux actually mentions "APIs" in its "what can I post". So that is probably the best fit in this case. superuser is certainly wrong.